# snowflake error View columns mismatch with view definition for view 'XYZ' at line 0, position -1, please re-create the view

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

We are attempting to use a database role to share views via a share object.

We get this error when granting a database role to a share. After getting this error, we recreated the view to no avail.

We recreated the view and expected the grant to succeed.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the ddl for the view and the command that is actually generating this error - all as editable text

Comment: Also include the ddl for the objects that the view is referencing